# codeigniter ion auth getting user id

Tags: codeigniter

I need to get the user id of the person logged in, so that i can run a query for that user. Im using ion auth, should i use a session or call it from the db, should i use a helper or not? anyway, heres what im trying to do:

example: how many work orders does logged in user have?
query would be: select * from work_orders WHERE status = "1" AND userid = "%THE LOGGED IN USER"

here is my controller, which doesnt have the "get user id" code:

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $data['total_open_wo'] = $this->Home_model->total_open_wo();
    $data['result'] = $this->Home_model->index();
    $this->load->view('home', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');

}
```

here is my model:

```
public function total_open_wo()  {

        $this->db->where('status', "1");
        $this->db->where('tid', "NEED_THE_USER_ID");
        $num = $this->db->count_all_results('work_orders');

        return ($num);
    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Provided the user is logged in you can get the user ID by using the `get_user_id()` function in ion auth. On a related note in your model you need a `$this->db->from()` call to set the table to fetch the number of rows from.

```
public function total_open_wo() {
  $userId = $this->ion_auth->get_user_id();
  $this->db->where('status', '1');
  $this->db->where('tid', $userId);
  $this->db->from('work_orders');
  $num = $this->db->count_all_results();

  return $num;
}
```

Use the function `$this->ion_auth->logged_in()` to make sure that the user is logged in before calling the model function.

Answer (score 14):

you can retrieve the logged in user details using **[user()](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/#user)** method.

For example to get user id

```
echo $this->ion_auth->user()->row()->id;
```