# How to get user id after registration ? in Ion Auth library

Tags: php, codeigniter, ion-auth

If user register then return user ID

```
$user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
$user_id = $user->id;
```

but `$user_id` is returned as `NULL`.

```
$this->ion_auth->register($username, $password, $email, $additional_data, $group)
```

this code also used but null error occurs.

Comment: you can post your registration code..

Comment: May be this below link will help you [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136142/codeigniter-ion-auth-getting-user-id)

Comment: How you register your user? you should use `$this->ion_auth->register($username, $password, $email, $additional_data, $group)` and that method return ID of user.

Comment: $this->ion_auth->register($username, $password, $email, $additional_data, $group)   this code also used but null error occure

Comment: does the new user appear in database? If not, the problem could be not passing all variables required by the method, or these variables are not the type they sould be.

Answer (score 0):

The default table for storing user data is 'users' not 'user'

Answer (score 0):

The `$this->ion_auth->register();` method returns the ID of the user if the user was successfully registered.
You can use it as follows:

```
$id = $this->ion_auth->register($username, $password, $email, $additional_data, $group);
```

Now `$id` will be containing the ID of the registered user (i.e. if the registration was successful).